# Clean sequences from a LinkedList

Tags: c++

*Edited*
I have to remove from a LinkedList sequences which their sum equals to 5.

for example for this Linked list: `{3,2, 1, 4, 10,3,3,2,1}` I get {10, 3, 3, 2, 1}. I dont really know why it's like that, it should remove 3,2 also but it dosent.

```
void LinkedList::cleanFive(LinkedList& list)
{
head = list.GetHead();

Node* end = head;
Node* headd = head;
Node* flag = head;
Node* curr = head;

int sum = 0;


while (end) {
    sum += end->data;

    if (sum < 5) {
        end = end->next;
    }
    if (sum == 5) {
        end = end->next;
        headd = end;
        flag = headd;
        head = flag;
        sum = 0;
    }
    if (sum > 5) {
        flag = head;
        curr = end;
        end = end->next;
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why does this take a parameter and why does it take over the parameter's head node? Shouldn't it remove such a sequence from itself?

Comment: The best tools for fixing (and creating) pointer-related code is pen(cil) and paper. Draw your list and figure out what should happen. Then compare that to what does happen.

Comment: In your example, you try `3 + 4`, it exceeds 5, whereupon you start counting again from 1 and miss `4 + 1` sequence. You need to advance `curr` by one element, not all the way to the end; and at the same time, subtract `curr->data` from `sum` to account for the sequence getting shorter.

Comment: What is the expected output in case of `{3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 5}`, `{}`?

Comment: @Bob__ in this particular case: { }

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: I have edited the code to a new one. I dont really know whats the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curr = head;
end = head;
currprev = nullptr;

std::vector<Node*> flag;
while(end) {
     sum += end->data;
     if (sum < 5) {
         flag.push_back(end);
         end = end->next;
     }

     if (sum > 5) {
         currprev = curr;
         curr = curr->next;
         end = curr;
         sum = 0;
         empty_flag()
     }

     if (sum == 5) {
         curr = end->next;
         end = curr;
         sum = 0;
         delete_nodes_from_flag_from_linked_list()
         empty_flag()
     }
```

}

Here is a possible solution. flag is in this case a vector of nodes which are saved until the sum is proven to be 5 or greater as 5. With flag there are two operations which need to be made: empy_flag() - deletes all entries from the vector and delete_nodes_from_flag_from_linked_list() - that deletes the elements from flag from the linked list.

Code for delete_nodes_from_flag_from_linked_list() should be as follows:

```
auto it = flag.end();
it--;
Node* last = *it;

if (currprev)
    currprev->next = last->next;
else
    head = last->next

for (auto f : flag) 
    delete f;
```

where currprev is the element just before curr. You have to keep track of this element from the beginning, unless your linked list elements keep pointers to previous elements. I am updating the code from above. head is the start of the list.

Comment: how do I implement this?
         delete_nodes_from_flag_from_linked_list()

Comment: Please see revised anwer.

Comment: Could you please mark as anwer if it is a correct answer ?